# Calling Controller method from js.erb in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have been trying to call a controller method(to delete a record) from js.erb file. What I have:

```
var selection = confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete the record?");

if(selection == true){
    new Ajax.Request('/students/destroy', {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: "#{student.id}"}
            });
    alert("deleted");
}
```

This delete.js.erb is invoked when user clicks on 'delete' button. I'm trying to call to destroy method from js.erb when the user confirms the deletion. Please let me know how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: why not just use the rails way `remote: true` ? or you have to use jquery?

Comment: Have you tried with <℅= @student.id > ? What is exactly your controller variable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(selection == true){
    var student_id = <%= student.id %>;
    $.ajax({
       type: "DELETE",
       url: "/students/"+ student_id +"/destroy", # instead use the destroy path like <%= student_path(student) %>
       success: function (result) {
         window.alert("success!!");
       },
       error: function (){
         window.alert("something wrong!");
       }
   });
}
```

Your type must be `delete`. and I suppose you are using `Jquery`.

BTW, this is not the right approach. You should use ajax rendering.